# How to Implement LIKE BINARY Case Sensitive Search on Rails Ransnack?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, search, ransack

I am trying to ransack for one of my models for a search form with the following code.

```
customer_ransack = customer.ransack(params[:q]).result
```

The above command is calling the following SQL query

```
SELECT `customer`.* FROM `customer` WHERE `customer`.`client_id` = 2 AND (((((`customer`.`first_name` LIKE '%hello%') OR (`customer`.`last_name` LIKE '%hello%')) ) AND `customer`.`invitation_status` IN ('accepted')) ORDER BY `customer`.`id` ASC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

And this is returning case insensitive result.
That means: For **Project** & **project**, the results are the same.

Now, I want to concatenate **BINARY** which my SQL to get the case sensitive result.

But I am now sure how to do this in the ransack.
So, is there anyone who can enlighten me?

Comment: @TomLord, MySQL does not have an `ILIKE` operator as for example PostgreSQL does. Case-sensitivity is determined by the collation of the string operands, so the standard `LIKE` comparison may be case-sensitive or case-insensitive.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks for your comment.
In my case, it was collation issue that is now fixed.